# Where is the inline code placed in this specific scenario?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am taking the time to look into the Linux kernel source and found a source of confusion. In the header file `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/fs.h` the following exist;

```
2183 static inline void unregister_chrdev(unsigned int major, const char *name)
2184 {
2185     __unregister_chrdev(major, 0, 256, name);
2186 }
```

I can not find any definitions for `__unregister_chrdev()` except in `/proc/kallsyms` and `Module.symvers`.

```
foo@bar:/usr/src$ cat /proc/kallsyms | grep "__unregister_chrdev$"
ffffffff810fd400 T __unregister_chrdev
foo@bar:/usr/src$

foo@bar:/usr/src$ grep -R '__unregister_chrdev' *
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64/Module.symvers:0x6bc3fbc0   __unregister_chrdev vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/fs.h:extern void __unregister_chrdev(unsigned int major, unsigned int baseminor,
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/fs.h:    __unregister_chrdev(major, 0, 256, name);
foo@bar:/usr/src$
```

As I understand it, inline functions will replace the call of itself with the content defined in the function, but in this instance the content of itself is a call to a new function. Does that mean that I can call `__unregister_chrdev(major, 0, 256, name)` directly somehow without changing anything significant? What is happening here?

Comment: Take a look at fs/char_dev.c. It's in there.

Comment: I saw a referance to that file, but a search of the whole tree tells me I do not have this file anywhere.

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/char_dev.c?v=3.2

Comment: @Mogget are you sure you have the actual kernel sources installed, and not just the header/build files needed to compile a module ?

Comment: You appear to be looking in the kernel headers package, and not in the kernel source package.  The first just gives you the bare essentials needed to compile modules, etc against, not the actual code that makes up a kernel.

Comment: Ah, yes, I only have the kernel headers it seems. Installing the linux-source-3.2 now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the internal function or its prototype may change.

You should always call the external one.

Optimized builds will treat this like a macro and effectively call the internal function.

Comment: Ah, so this is a way of protecting the "user" so that the person can always assume that the function stays the same even though the implementation changes?

Comment: Exactly. The outer function is called an API function. It's like a contract between developers. The internals can change without notice since they are not part of the contract.

Answer (score 0):

char_dev.c 
 http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/char_dev.c#L331

/**
 * __unregister_chrdev - unregister and destroy a cdev

- @major: major device number
- @baseminor: first of the range of minor numbers
- @count: the number of minor numbers this cdev is occupying
- @name: name of this range of devices
  *
- Unregister and destroy the cdev occupying the region described by
- @major, @baseminor and @count.  This function undoes what
- __register_chrdev() did.
  */

void __unregister_chrdev(unsigned int major, unsigned int baseminor,
             unsigned int count, const char *name)

{

```
struct char_device_struct *cd;

cd = __unregister_chrdev_region(major, baseminor, count);
if (cd && cd->cdev)
    cdev_del(cd->cdev);
kfree(cd);
```

}

Inline functions are usually located in header files, because the compiler can only inline source code, not object code. Inlining is done by the compiler, not the linker, it must be done on source code not object files.

gcc are free to ignore any such requests to inline functions, as well as to inline functions without the keyword. https://www.kernel.org/doc/local/inline.html